# I'm having a minor problem running Tensorflow with Colab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am a beginner who just learned about TensorFlow using Google Colab.
As in the attached image file, numbers 10 to 13 are underlined in `tensorflow.keras~`, what is the problem?
It's probably a function that indicates a typo, but there's nothing wrong with running it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhGV4.png)

Comment: Post code instead of screenshots

Answer (score 0):

This underline error was an ongoing issue earlier in **Google Colab**, which is resolved now. Please try again replicating the same code in **Google colab** what you mentioned in the screen shot and let us know if the issue still persists at your end.

Please check the code below: (I replicated the same in **Google Colab** with `python 3.8.10` and `TensorFlow 2.9.2`)

[image]

`from keras.preprocessing import Sequence` will show the error as you are not giving proper alias to import the [Sequence API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/pad_sequences) which is provided correctly in next line (using `tensorflow.keras.preprocessing` prefix or `tensorflow.keras.utils`).